# How to find the sum of the infinite series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

So I just started learning series, and I am having trouble understanding them. I have a series below: 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)2^n}$$

Can someone explain to me how I should go about this, from start to finish? I couldn't find any online websites that explained how to find sums, so if you have that, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Here is a detailed way to find the answer. Hopefully, that'll give you some insight you can use for similar questions.*

1. $\frac{1}{2}$ is just a number; your series is just a number. To rely on the whole power and flexibility of real analysis, functions are more useful. The first trick is to define the function
   $$
   f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{2n+1}\tag{1}
   $$
   which is defined for all $x\in(-1,1)$. *(Can you argue why?)*
   Then what you want to compute is $f(1/2)$.
2. Why does it help? So far, it's not clear, but what is inside the sum (i.e., the summands) *kind of* looks like a derivative.  In particular, if I look at
   $$
   g(x) = x f(x^2) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\tag{2}
   $$
   then it should be clear that the $n$-th summand looks like the antiderivative (with regard to $x$) of $x^{2n}$. Also, note that the original problem is now to compute $g(1/\sqrt{2})\cdot\sqrt{2}$, so we're not losing track of the end goal. *(Note: $g$ is also defined on $(-1,1)$: do you see why?)*
3. Here is the fun part. One can actually argue, using theorems about *power series* within their radius of convergence, that the above eyeballing is justified. Namely, we **do** have
   $$
   g'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}
   = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}
   = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{2n}\tag{3}
   $$
   *(The tricky part here is arguing that swapping $\sum$ and $\frac{d}{dx}$ is alright.)*
4. But *we know how to compute that derivative!* For $x\in(-1,1)$, this is the sum of a geometric series:
   $$
   g'(x) 
   = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x^2)^{n}
   = \frac{1}{1-x^2}\tag{4}
   $$
5. We're almost done. All that remains is to... integrate that explicit derivative we found to get back the expression for $g$: recalling from the expression in (2) that $g(0)=0$ (to help us figure out the constant of integration),
   $$
   g(x) = g(0) + \int\frac{1}{1-x^2} = 0 + \frac12 \log\frac{1+x}{1-x}\tag{5}
   $$
6. We are done:
   $$
   f(1/2) = {g(1/\sqrt2)}\cdot{\sqrt{2}} = \boxed{\frac1{\sqrt{2}} \log(3+2\sqrt2)} \approx 1.246
   $$

Comment: The only part left out is how to compute that integral. It's a rather standard one, though.

Comment: +1 I learnt a new term "eyeballing".

Comment: Why do we calculate it at f(1/2)?

Comment: @Theboyboy Because $x^n=1/2^n$ when $x=1/2$.

Comment: Thank you. One more question, how did you find the bounds?

Comment: Which bounnds? @Theboyboy

Comment: The bound of x (-1,1) in the beginning. And let me guess. We calculate g at 1/ $\sqrt$ 2 because of a similar reason as your last comment

Comment: @Theboyboy yes (for $1/\sqrt2$). For the interval $(-1,1)$ (the "radius of convergence" of the power series is 1), it's because the series diverges for $|x|>1$ (easy to check, as $|x|^n/(2n+1)\to\infty$ when $n\to\infty$ then). And the series converges for $|x|<1$. (Technically, you can also check that the series converges at $x=-1$ and diverges at $x=1$, but we don't need that.)

Answer (score 2):

Using inverse hyperbolic tangent's [Maclaurin series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHyperbolicTangent.html) $\text{arctanh} x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1},$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)2^n}&=\sqrt2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n+1}\left(\frac1{\sqrt 2}\right)^{2n+1}\\
&=\sqrt2\text{arctanh}\left(\frac1{\sqrt2} \right)\\
&=\sqrt2\cdot\frac12\left(\ln\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)-\ln\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\right)\\
&=\sqrt2\ln(1+\sqrt2)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Try factoring the argument as 1/(2n+1)*1/2^n. Then do backwards long division on the 1st fraction I wrote. This should allow you to condense the entire thing into a geometric series. From there you can use S=a/(1-r).